# Unit test failures after iText Upgrade to 7.2.2 from 7.1.4

Tags: java, gradle, itext7

Due to security conecers, we were asked to upgrade the iText library from 7.1.4 to 7.2.2. Once I upgraded the see most of the Unit tests are failing due to the following errors

1. java.lang.AssertionError: There was an exception in  testHandleEventcom.itextpdf.kernel.exceptions.PdfException: Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.
2. com.itextpdf.kernel.exceptions.PdfException: Trailer not found.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The code being tested may use the library incorrectly!

Comment: How can I detect that?

Comment: No idea.  You are the one with the code.  You may want to tell your manager that this is a non/trivial upgrade so more resources can be allocated.

Comment: Just like @Thorbjørn says, in particular the first error indicates that you incorrectly use the iText APIs. And it quite clearly says what the error is, your code puts an indirect object from one document into another. You should copy instead (all `PdfObject`s have a `copyTo` method). The second error might be a follow-up error as some original error failed to create some document.